# Cisco ASA site to site with Forcepoint stonesoft NGFW

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, site-to-site

I am try to establish a site to site VPN between Cisco ASA and Forcepoint Stonesoft NGFW, i have support that assured everything is set up correct from Forcepoint NGFW side but i have trouble from cisco ASA.

So this is my network map

[image]

My Cisco ASA with internal IP 192.168.4.12 behind another Fortinet firewall that is connected to another ISP router that is doing the nating to the internet.
Making the Cisco ASA as the initiator of VPN tunnel hence it has no static public IP just a dynamic public IP.

```
CiscoFW# show run
: Saved
:

: Hardware:   ASA5510, 1024 MB RAM, CPU Pentium 4 Celeron 1600 MHz
:
ASA Version 9.1(7)32
!
hostname CiscoFW
enable password REMOVED encrypted
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any6
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any6
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any6 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any6 eq domain
passwd removed encrypted
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
nameif outside
security-level 0
ip address 192.168.4.12 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/1
nameif inside
security-level 100
ip address 10.177.1.77 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/2
shutdown
nameif dmz
security-level 50
no ip address
!
interface Ethernet0/3
shutdown
no nameif
no security-level
no ip address
!
interface Management0/0
shutdown
no nameif
no security-level
no ip address
!
boot system disk0:/asa917-32-k8.bin
ftp mode passive
object network obj_any
subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
object network NGFW-Internal
subnet 10.77.0.0 255.255.0.0
description NGFW-Internal
object network NETWORK_OBJ_10.177.1.0_24
subnet 10.177.1.0 255.255.255.0
access-list outside_access_in extended permit icmp any any
access-list 100 extended permit icmp any any
access-list outside_cryptomap_1 extended permit ip 10.177.1.0 255.255.255.0 object NGFW-Internal
pager lines 24
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu dmz 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (inside,outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_10.177.1.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_10.177.1.0_24 destination static NGFW-Internal NGFW-Internal no-proxy-arp route-lookup
!
object network obj_any
nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.4.9 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
http server enable
http 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0 outside
http 10.177.1.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal NGFW-TSv2
protocol esp encryption 3des
protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto map outside_map0 2 match address outside_cryptomap_1
crypto map outside_map0 2 set peer 90.90.10.10
crypto map outside_map0 2 set ikev1 phase1-mode aggressive group5
crypto map outside_map0 2 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal NGFW-TSv2
crypto map outside_map0 interface outside
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto isakmp identity key-id itmanager@whatever.com
crypto ikev2 policy 1
encryption aes-256
integrity sha
group 5 2
prf sha
lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 10
encryption aes-192
integrity sha
group 5 2
prf sha
lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 20
encryption aes
integrity sha
group 5 2
prf sha
lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 30
encryption 3des
integrity sha
group 5 2
prf sha
lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 40
encryption des
integrity sha
group 5 2
prf sha
lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 enable outside
crypto ikev1 enable outside
crypto ikev1 policy 10
authentication pre-share
encryption aes-256
hash sha
group 2
lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 20
authentication rsa-sig
encryption aes-256
hash sha
group 2
lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 40
authentication pre-share
encryption aes-192
hash sha
group 2
lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 50
authentication rsa-sig
encryption aes-192
hash sha
group 2
lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 70
authentication pre-share
encryption aes
hash sha
group 2
lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 80
authentication rsa-sig
encryption aes
hash sha
group 2
lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 100
authentication pre-share
encryption 3des
hash sha
group 2
lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 110
authentication rsa-sig
encryption 3des
hash sha
group 2
lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 130
authentication pre-share
encryption des
hash sha
group 2
lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 140
authentication rsa-sig
encryption des
hash sha
group 2
lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh 10.177.1.0 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh timeout 60
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
group-policy GroupPolicy-Ngfw internal
group-policy GroupPolicy-Ngfw attributes
vpn-idle-timeout none
vpn-session-timeout none
vpn-filter none
vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev2
username admin password REMOVED encrypted privilege 15
tunnel-group 90.90.10.10 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 90.90.10.10  general-attributes
default-group-policy GroupPolicy-Ngfw
tunnel-group 90.90.10.10  ipsec-attributes
ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key Cisco123
ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key Cisco123
!
!
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous
call-home
profile CiscoTAC-1
no active
destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
destination address email callhome@cisco.com
destination transport-method http
subscribe-to-alert-group diagnostic
subscribe-to-alert-group environment
subscribe-to-alert-group inventory periodic monthly
subscribe-to-alert-group configuration periodic monthly
subscribe-to-alert-group telemetry periodic daily
Cryptochecksum:f9e367f14ff7742459421745f6228a1e
: end
```

And this is the fortinet configuration file

https://837-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/hadi_altaha_ae7_com/ETGP3wjIrLpKm3LN91Dk4K8BhMoqfOOyW40NqQeRk3PtDA?e=7lTfQ1

And this is the Cisco ASA debug logs

https://837-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/hadi_altaha_ae7_com/EW9Zrh678ZhGnPEeyBCohmgBmmOl9f2V6ewfRrXyT4T_jQ?e=KNSIsD

The tunnel doesn't come up

Comment: I think we'll have to see the config of the Fortinet firewall to see if the outgoing protocols are allowed and to see that there is a NAT for the incoming traffic.

Comment: Sure! coming up

Comment: Hello Hadi and welcome.  Could you say what isn't working?  Do you have any logs or error messages showing how far it gets?

Comment: NB when you post configs, you need to ensure they have no passwords in them which you're still using.

Comment: Jonathan, the tunnel is not coming up, i will post the logs of the cisco asa as well

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, the passwords are tampered by me and they are not working, but thank you for your care

Comment: @HadiQJ, when you do post configs, please change the password to something that doesn't look like it may be the password. If you don't it is unclear if the password is real or not and we have members of the community that will flag it for moderator attention. While members can edit a post, it takes a moderator or SE staff to modify the edit history. Our community tries to protect users from mistakenly posting passwords, but it is much simpler if you change the password to something that is clearly not the password (REMOVED, XXXXX, <password>, etc).

Comment: The first thing I notice is that in the config, your peer address is 90.90.10.10, but your debugs show the peer address as 91.75.29.58.  Did you sanitize the address in your config?

Comment: I may be wrong, but it appears the Forcepoint is using IKEv1, but the ASA is using IKEv2.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the debugs, the traffic isn't passing through the Fortinet firewall. They show some traffic sending out to 91.75.29.58 and receiving in to 10.177.1.x (your inside interface!), but nothing from the remote endpoint 90.90.x.x. These couple of addresses seem very odd and I wonder if the debug is even from the current ASA.

I think you need to get the Fortinet squared away to pass the traffic through to the ASA before anything else.

Comment: Due to my paranoia i changed the Forcepoint NGFW side from 91.75.29.58 to 90.90.10.10 but you got me there because i need help!